# Flutter LiveData to watch sqlite query result changes

Tags: sqlite, flutter, android-livedata

I am trying to show how many row of record in my transaction table. In android, I am able to use livedata to observe the data changes without additional step like retreive result of row count after insert or delete. But in flutter, I need to do the additional step.

I already try using stream and bloc pattern, but additional step still require to call in bloc after add or delete.

```
  Future<List<TempPremixDetailWithIp>> getAll() async {
    var db = await AppDb().database;
    var res = await db.rawQuery("""
    SELECT 
    temp_premix_detail.*,
    item_packing.sku_code,
    item_packing.sku_name
    FROM temp_premix_detail
    LEFT JOIN item_packing ON temp_premix_detail.item_packing_id = 
  item_packing.id
    ORDER BY temp_premix_detail.id DESC
    """);
    List<TempPremixDetailWithIp> list = res.isNotEmpty
        ? res.map((c) => TempPremixDetailWithIp.fromJson(c)).toList()
        : [];
    return list;
  }


  _loadTempPremixDetailList() async {
    final list = await TempPremixDetailDao().getAll();
    _tempPremixDetailListSubject.add(list);
  }

  deleteTempPremixDetail(int itemPackingId) async {
    await TempPremixDetailDao().deleteById(itemPackingId);
    await _loadTempPremixDetailList();
    await _loadItemPackingList();
  }
```